# How do I get an atom enclosure image out using Simple Pie

Tags: rss, silverstripe, atom-feed, simplepie

I am building an RSS aggregator and trying to handle images from a broad range of sources.

The majority of my sources are using images in the content or media:RSS enclosures.

I have managed to get Simple Pie to pick up enclosures for media:RSS

and also to strip images from the content of an RSS post.

But feeds from a CMS called Silver Stripe have an embedded image in each post with an atom style

notation that I cannot get Simple Pie to read and extract images from.

```html
<link rel="enclosure" type="image/JPG" href="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
```

Do I need to modify the enclosure class to get this to work or am I missing something, is it

something to do with the namespaces I am using?

[Here is one of the feeds I am trying to get](http://www.nmit.ac.nz/nmit-news/rss)

I am accessing about 7 other different SilverStipe sites, all of these include the same image links...

Here is my current image script:

```php
if ($enclosures = $prPost->get_enclosures())
    {
        foreach ($enclosures as $enclosure)
        {
            $this->Fields['image'] = $enclosure->get_link();
        }
    }

    if (preg_match('/<img.+?src="(.+?)"/', $this->Fields['desc'], $matches) && strlen($this->Fields['image']) < 5) {
        $this->Fields['image'] = $matches[1];
        $this->Fields['desc'] = preg_replace('/<img(.*)>/i' , "" , $this->Fields['desc'], 1); 
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at solutions like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) which normalizes all of a entries's links and images whether it's RSS or Atom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These `link` elements are children of the `item` elements:

```
<rss>
  <channel>
    ...
    <item>
      ...
      <description>...</description>
      <link rel="enclosure" ... />
```

You can use [`get_item_tags`](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_item_tags) to get specific elements from an `item`.

They *should* be in the Atom namespace (`<atom:link>`), but are instead left in the default namespace (`<link>`), which is a bug in the feed. but one you'll need to work around:

```
$links = $item->get_item_tags(SIMPLEPIE_NAMESPACE_RSS_20, 'link');
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you Joe! That is exactly what I needed! I used a foreach loop to retrieve the last link and $item['attribs'][SIMPLEPIE_NAMESPACE_RSS_20]['href']; got the URL of the image for silverstripes malformed feeds.